# What are these bugs in my morning glories

Tags: bugs, morning-glory

[image]

These are the bugs that are in my morning glories I don’t know what they are. Could these be what’s leaving the white stuff on back of leaves? The white stuff also has black specs in the middle of it. Please help.

Comment: It's a bit too small to really see what they are. Do they have wings or not? 6 legs? Do they jump when stressed?

Comment: A photo of an affected leaf would be useful...

Comment: What color are they and are they soft-bodied or not?

Comment: Hi everyone, I did post a picture of the leaves it’s white stuff with black dots in the middle and these bugs almost look like a spider but they do fly. They are so small it’s hard to get a good pic of them. The other picture of leaves is under what is attacking my morning glories and how to get rid of it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP stated that this was an accidental post in an attempt to add more photos to an existing question.

Comment: @Stephie yes was trying to post more pics. Thanks